# What is the most efficient way to invert two words?

Tags: substitute

Let's say that I have a file containing several occurrences of the word `foo` and several
occurrences of the word `bar`.

I need to make all the words `foo` become `bar` and inversely all the words
`bar` become `foo`.

What is the most efficient way to do that?

---

My first thought was to make it 3 steps:

- First make `bar` become something temporary: `%s/bar/barTEMP/g`
- Then make `foo` become `bar`: `:%s/foo/bar/g`
- Finally substitute `barTEMP`: `:%s/barTEMP/foo/g`

It is an implementation of a classical algorithm to switch the value of two
variables but is there a more efficient way to do this?

---

I know I can write a function to do the 3 substitutions for me but
what I'm wondering is if there is a different method than using a temporary
substitution. For example I was thinking maybe something could be done by using
an `|` in the search pattern:

```
:%s/\(foo\|bar\)/???/g
```

But that would require to make the replacement string change depending on the
actually matched word and I don't know how to do that. *(Note that this idea is
just an example, if someone come up with something better that would be nice
too)*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9273857/1924583

Comment: I suppose [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/766093/1924583) is the original source with full commentary on how it works.

Comment: Tim Pope's [abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) provides some syntactic sugar for it: `:%S/{foo,bar}/{bar,foo}/g`. This works well as long as you don't want to match only whole words.

Comment: I usually use the ternary operator in a replacement expression for just two words (not very obviously at `:h expr1`), though using a dictionary is obviously better for >2 words.

Comment: @SatoKatsura: Thanks! I had seen this plugin before but totally forgot it could do that. Currently I'm trying to reduce the number of plugins I use so that's not the solution I'm going to use but that is still good to know!

Comment: @Antony: I guess for a 2 words substitution like in my question, the ternary operator is the best way to go because it is lighter than a dictionary. (And thanks for the reminder about `:h expr1` I always forget how to find it!

Comment: Yeah, it took me several minutes to find it, so, when I finally did, I thought I'd better mention where it was. :-)

Comment: Just adding in the actual command for using the ternary operator as @Antony suggested: `:%s/foo\|bar/\=submatch(0) == "foo" ? "bar" : "foo"/g` in case non-programmers want to use it.

Answer (score 15):

Posting this so it can have an answer on our SE, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765894/can-i-substitute-multiple-items-in-a-single-regular-expression-in-vim-or-perl/766093#766093) is this source with full explanation.

Here's a good way to use a single regex to do multiple substitutions:

```
:%s/foo\|bar/\={'foo':'bar','bar':'foo'}[submatch(0)]/g
```

See [`:help sub-replace-expression`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#sub-replace-expression) and [`:help Dictionary`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#Dictionary) for Vim's documentation on how this works.

Comment: Thanks for this one, I didn't saw it on SO. That seems like a good way to go.

Comment: Just mentioning the solution using the ternary operator that @Antony suggested above: `:%s/foo\|bar/\=submatch(0) == "foo" ? "bar" : "foo"/g`.

Answer (score 2):

For vanilla vim, [Tumbler41's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9089/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-invert-two-words/9090#9090) is probably the best way to go. If you are OK with installing plugins, you could use [tpope/vim-abolish](https://github.com/tpope/vim-abolish) to do this.

This plugin supplies *many* awesome feature, but the relevant one for this case is called "Subvert" (abbreviated to `:%S`. Essentially, it allows you to create a list of matches, and a list of replacements. I like the example from the README on the plugin, so I'll use that. If you want to change "child" to "adult", while simultaneously changing "children" to "adults", that is a single subvert command.

```
:%S/child{,ren}/adult{,s}/
```

In your case, you could do

```
:%S/{foo,bar}/{bar,foo}
```

One important note about this approach is that it doesn't support regexes very well, and it defaults to case-sensitive, so it would also change "FOO" to "BAR".  However, for simple substitutions, this approach is very simple and convenient.

Comment: `abolish` does support regexes, it's just that (1) it uses "very magic" mode, and (2) your regexes are likely to conflict with its own.  Like the vast majority of Vim plugins, it's an useful hack, not a rock-solid solution.

Comment: You mean “it defaults to case-*insensitive*,” right?

Comment: [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Supercharged substitution with :Subvert]http://vimcasts.org/episodes/supercharged-substitution-with-subvert/)