# How can I make two substitution command in one line

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, vrapper

Giving these 2 substitution commands in vim:

```
%s/}$/\r}\r/g
%s/^\s*([a-zA-Z\#\.\:\s\(\)-\[\]'=]*)\s*\{/$1 \{/g
```

I have 2 questions:

- How can I join 2 substitution commands in a one line command ?
- Is there a better regex command to make this a oneliner ?

I know I could make a function with both commands, but I'm in Eclipse VRapper not in Vim itself. AFAIU I can't have functions in it.

**Edit**

That question suggested doesn't solve the problem, because these substitutions should be made one after the other. They convert a compiled sccs from nested to expanded output style. It's not just two occurences that can be substituted in text.

What I would like in the first question is something like this PHP code:

```
$w = "Hi Planet!";
echo str_replace("Hi", "Hello", str_replace("Planet", "World", $w));
// result: Hello World!
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the most efficient way to invert two words?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9089/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-invert-two-words)

Comment: Unrelated to your question: the syntax of your second `s/.../.../` command is wrong.  I presume it's inspired by Perl regexps, but it would be wrong even in Perl.  Either way, it has nothing to do with Vim.  Read `:h regexp` and `:h :substitute` to learn about Vim syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please show where it's wrong? both are working for me. I'm using VRapper on Eclipse, not Vim itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way to concatenate two commands in one line in Vim is to use a pipe `|`. Unlike shells, `|` in Vim is for sequential, conditional execution - it's more like a `&&` in shells.

So, in this case:

```
%s/}$/\r}\r/g | %s/^\s*([a-zA-Z\#\.\:\s\(\)-\[\]'=]*)\s*\{/$1 \{/g
```

Additional notes from [`:h :|`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar):

```
You can also use <NL> to separate commands in the same way as with '|'.  To
insert a <NL> use CTRL-V CTRL-J.  "^@" will be shown.  Using '|' is the
preferred method.  But for external commands a <NL> must be used, because a
'|' is included in the external command.  To avoid the special meaning of <NL>
it must be preceded with a backslash.  Example: 
        :r !date<NL>-join
This reads the current date into the file and joins it with the previous line.

Note that when the command before the '|' generates an error, the following
commands will not be executed.
```